# Getting Started with Sharpen in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sharpen-tool

I'm a .Net developer and recently I've become part of a project that is doing a port of some java software. I'm trying to get [Sharpen](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/reference/html/reference/sharpen.html) up and running to convert.

I have downloaded and installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Version: Helios Service Release 1 Build id: 20100917-0705).

I've been trying to follow this [Guide](http://developer.db4o.com/Blogs/Product/tabid/167/entryid/95/Default.aspx). Following instructions on how to set up sharpen, I've tried then to grab a copy of the sharpen repo at https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/sharpen/ from within eclipse. Host: source.db4o.com, Repository Path: source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/sharpen. Using various connection types I get connection refused when using anony username (or using ext I get Cannot run program "ssh":CreateProcess error=2, the system cannot find the file specified").

Alternatively, I am able to use subversion/toritiseSVN to download the repo at the above mentioned url. I then import this into my workspace, but I get various errors such as org.eclipse cannot be resolved. I know what this means, but I am unsure how to go about solving that problem.

Finally, the last step is to Export this as "Plug-in Development" -> "Deployable plugins and fragments". However, I don't see this as an export option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you behind a firewall or proxy server? Normally it is the main reason for `connection refused`. Also which SVN plugin are you using? By default eclipse IDE comes with CVS only. So putting the svn repo at https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/sharpen/ is bound to fail in CVS plugin.

As for your last question:

You have downloaded the basic **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers**. You will need the **Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers**. Checkout the eclipse comparison page: http://eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php.

Following are some SVN/eclipse links:

1. http://subclipse.tigris.org/
2. http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/

Hope this will help.

Comment: Bingo on both counts. I was using CVS and the basic IDE. Thanks!