# How to use sharpen with monodevelop?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, sharpen-tool

Sharpen

Sharpen is one of the best tool/plugin of Eclipse that helps to convert Java to C# with some special syntax. 1) ignore classes 2) ignore documentation 3) merge classes with others 4) translate specific methods to .net properties 5) translate specific methods to .net events

http://codecall.net/2014/03/27/best-tools-to-convert-java-to-c-source-code/

Everywhere it is proposed to use it [in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987695/getting-started-with-sharpen-in-eclipse). Is there any articles about sharpen for monodevelop?